# Using like to compare to a string in excel

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

What I want to match is this regex: `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$`

For example, how can I test whether the contents of `E2` are like `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]##########`, and can I wrap that into an `IF` statement?

Comment: Clarify your question please. Could you put some valid input and output? And should that `IF` return 1 here?

Comment: @Jerry if the regex matches in excel I want to five out `TRUE` else `FALSE`. My `E` column contains numbers which match with the regex.

Comment: Just to check: if E2 has the text `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$`, you want to get `TRUE`?

Comment: Yep, basically I want to check for such a number `ZAE000006284`

Comment: I didn't mean the meaning of the regex, I meant the literal text `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$`, but your latest comment confirms it. Excel formulas unfortunately cannot handle regex matching. You'll have to use VBA for this and perhaps create a custom function to do that.

Comment: I though about using `like`? Isn`t it possible to use this in a proper way?

Comment: @user2051347 It's not like SQL, there's no `LIKE` function.

Comment: VBA actually does have a `Like` operator which does some basic pattern-matching. Unfortunately I can't find a canonical reference for it.

Comment: @cyborg how to use `regexp` in an if statement?

Comment: @user2051347 It looks like you have an example `If` statement already; have you tried it?

Comment: You can follow this answer, and you don't need an if statement: stackoverflow.com/a/11906595/907578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Function regxMatch(Value As String, Pattern As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False)
    Dim r As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    r.Pattern = Pattern
    r.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    If r.Test(Value) Then
        M = "Matches '" & Pattern & "'"
    Else
        M = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Function should be self explanatory!

Comment: @user2051347 You might want to rename the function since there's already a function called `Match`. Maybe something like `regexmatch`.

Comment: @Jerry How can I use this function on my vba code? I am posting this as module in the vba editor, however I cannot open the function?

Comment: @user2051347 Save the module, then go to your sheet. You should be able to use the function `=regxMatch()` Well, I'm on 2007 and it's throwing me an error. I guess this could work on 2010.

Comment: Function is not self-explanatory as the `M` output is not returned to `RegxMatch`

Comment: @brettdj pls edit the answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a shorter test as such:

```
Function regexTest(strIn As String, strPattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegex.Pattern = strPattern
    regexTest = objRegex.test(strIn)
End Function
```

*test code*

```
Sub TestME()
MsgBox regexTest("ZAE000006284", "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$") ' False
MsgBox regexTest("ZA0000000628", "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$") ' True
End Sub
```